# How to get "Eclipse View" widget from SWT Library?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

As far as I understand, SWT is the GUI building block for Eclipse IDE. 
And in Eclipse, we have a concept of "View" widget, such as the following example:

[image: Eclipse View widget]

The "View" widget can be docked, minimized, maximized, and can also be made floated.
I think it will be useful for my project, but unfortunately can't find it in the standard SWT Widget shown here http://www.eclipse.org/swt/widgets/

How to create this widget in SWT? Can I just extract it from the SWT library. Or perhaps, it is shipped as extension to SWT?

Comment: Views are an Eclipse concept not SWT. They are built using SWT controls but you have to write an Eclipse plugin to use an Eclipse view.

Comment: Is there a way to easily integrate into SWT? Or is there any similar widget on SWT?

Comment: If you have not started implementing the project yet, you could consider to build your application upon the Eclipse RCP framework. Take a look at the following tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseRCP/article.html